# Potential Dividers - Why do I need the second resistor?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, voltage

So I am doing the OCR Physics GCSE course, and I have just learnt about potential dividers in electronic circuits. I get that the first resistor steps down the voltage so a component with a lower rating can be used, but why do you need the second resistor if you are going to connect a component in parallel anyway? Surely the component should act like a resistor and the potential difference of the component + that of the first resistor should equal the battery's voltage.

Comment: Calculate the potential after a single resistors, keeping in mind that the current depends on the total resistance.

Comment: But all components of a circuit have resistance, so shouldn't the second component act like a resistor and make the total resistance high enough to give the current. Anyways, shouldn't a second resistor and a component in parallel decrease the total resistance to below the second resistor, meaning you can no longer add the resistance of the two resistors to give the total resistance?

Comment: Don't presume: calculate. Carefully. Right now you are trying to intuit the answer, but your intuition isn't complete yet; you're using the wrong model in your head. The way to fix that is to work out the consequences of your proposal in detail. One detail to watch is how resistances combine differently in series and in parallel.

Comment: Alright I did the calculations, and if I ignore the resistance of the components (eg a lamp), then I can see the importance of a second resistor. Is that what I am supposed to do, like you ignore the resistance in a wire, do you also ignore the resistance of components excl. resistors?

Comment: If you are working in a lab actually use of an additional  resistor in the circuit helps you to control the output which you wish to utilize in some additional experiment where you need a potential difference of certain range...suppose you have 12 v  battery but you need only 2v in a certain expt. so you control the current in the main circuit through this resistor so that the divider can work in the range of 2 volts.

Comment: I see, but in calculations, would you say that at GCSE level, it is okay to ignore any resistance from components and only look at the resistors?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a known load $R'$, you can divide the potential of a source with a single resistor. If your source voltage is $V$ and you want a voltage $V'$ across the load, you can write

$$V' = \frac{R'}{R_L+R'}V$$

from which you solve for $R_L$, the load.

However, if you don't know $R'$ (or if it can change - for example, as a light bulb heats up, its resistance increases) or if you really don't want the terminals where the load is connected to exceed the voltage $V'$ (it might present a dangerous voltage in the absence of a load), it would be good if you could at least "pre-regulate" the voltage by using a divider.

In electronics, we recognize something called the "stiffness" of a divider: this is a measure of how much the voltage at the divider changes when the load resistance changes. A divider where the second resistor is open (infinite) is not at all stiff; as the pair of resistors making up the divider become smaller (in a constant ratio) compared to the load resistor, the divider becomes stiffer.

So while it is possible to have a "divider" with a single resistor, in practice that's rarely how it's done.